# Google app engine not execute javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Aim to insert http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/ to -> http://snyderome.appspot.com/
but i have only garlbled code

```
<html><body><link rel="stylesheet" ref="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="myfirstchart" style="height: 350px;width: 800px;">90000</div>
```

last part always disappears. I am at stack .

```
<script type="text/javascript >
new Morris.Line({
element: 'myfirstchart',
 data: [
{ year: '2008', value: 20 },
{ year: '2009', value: 10 },
{ year: '2010', value: 5 },
{ year: '2011', value: 5 },
{ year: '2012', value: 20 }],
 xkey: 'year',
 ykeys: ['value'],
 labels: ['Value']
 }); </script>
```

Comment: What means last part?

Comment: Are you outputting this through a templating engine like jinja2? They often strip script tags, and even other tags from content that is is inserted into the template.

Comment: I would include the script, style, and link tags in the head of your document first. You already have morris.js included there, but it's a min file meaning the file has been minimized to reduce size. Looking at the HTML for the page you've linked to perhaps you should visit http://www.w3schools.com and do some of their tutorials.

Comment: You should also work through this: http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js, everything you need is there. I took the HTML from your linked page and got this working in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a quote character (") at the end of "text/javascript"

Comment: You are also hardcoding http instead of //https and that will prevent loading on most browsers.